# I cannot find a way to access my css files dynamically using JavaScript in Django

Tags: javascript, css, django, dynamic

I am new to Django. I would like to change my stylesheet dynamically but everything I have has fallen flat. This seems like it should be a simple problem.

Here is my code so far:

```
function ChangeStyle(sheet){

         if (sheet=='stylesheet/StyleSheet.css'){
           sheet={% static "stylesheets/StyleSheet.css"%}
         }else {
           sheet = "{% static "stylesheets/webdefault.css" %}"
         }


    document.getElementById('UserStyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    }





<button onclick="ChangeStyle('stylesheets/StyleSheet.css')">Alternate                    Style</button>
<button onclick="ChangeStyle('stylesheets/webdefault.css')">Default      Style</button>
```

I have tried:

```
 <button onclick="ChangeStyle("{% static "stylesheets/webdefault.css" %}")">Alternate Style</button>
```

For each style.

Comment: String comparison in JavaScript involves the `==` or `===` operators, not `=`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Thanks.

Comment: In the first "sheet = path'" you forgot the quotes "".

Comment: I put those in, sorry brain fart. It is probably because I have tried so many different ways to make it work. The buttons aren't sending the onclick parameter to the function.